# Import a CSV file into an Oracle External Table

Tags: oracle, external-tables, csv-import

I have seen various similar questions to this but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I have been given a CSV file produced on a mainframe that I need to load up into Oracle. I decided to try and map it in an Oracle external table and then use this to get it inserted into Oracle.

This is my CSV:

```
CONTRACT_NUMBER,PRODUCTCODE,TRANSACTION_NUMBER,EFFECTIVE_DATE,AMENDMENT,TERM,ACTIVE,AGENT_NUMBER,PREMIUM,ICRATE,RCRATE,IC_ALLOW,RC_ALLOW,SPRATE,TRANSACTION_CODE,TRANSACTION_DATE,AGENT_CATEGORY,AGENT_SALES_CODE,FREQ,TOT_PREMTD,REFERENCE,ALTERNATIVE_COMMISSION_METHOD,PAXUS_REF_ID
PAXUSCT1,MAA,1,07/10/2017,NB,12,Y,2905,6000,,,1,1,,T642,,,,,6000,,,
PAXUSCT1,MAA,2,07/05/2018,INC,11,Y,2905,2400,90,3,1,1,,,,,,,8400,,,
PAXUSCT2,MAA,1,01/06/2018,NB,12,Y,T1000,540,,,1,1,,,,,,,540,,,
PAXUSCT3,MAA,1,05/06/2018,NB,12,Y,T1000,1200,,,1,1,,,,,,,1200,,,
```

I created this definition, and many other variations of this but I keep getting errors:

```
create table LD_CMS_BASIS_MIGRATION
(
  contract_number               VARCHAR2(8),
  productcode                   VARCHAR2(3),
  transaction_number            NUMBER,
  effective_date                DATE,
  amendment                     VARCHAR2(3),
  term                          NUMBER,
  active                        VARCHAR2(1),
  agent_number                  VARCHAR2(5),
  premium                       NUMBER,
  icrate                        NUMBER,
  rcrate                        NUMBER,
  ic_allow                      NUMBER,
  rc_allow                      NUMBER,
  sprate                        NUMBER,
  transaction_code              VARCHAR2(4),
  transaction_date              DATE,
  agent_category                VARCHAR2(4),
  agent_sales_code              VARCHAR2(4),
  freq                          VARCHAR2(1),
  tot_premtd                    NUMBER,
  reference                     VARCHAR2(40),
  alternative_commission_method VARCHAR2(40),
  paxus_ref_id                  VARCHAR2(8)
)
organization external
(
  type ORACLE_LOADER
  default directory MIGRATIONS
  access parameters 
  (
    records field names all files
    fields CSV without embedded record terminators
  )
  location (MIGRATIONS:'CMS_BASIS_MIG.csv')
)
reject limit UNLIMITED;
```

When I try to read from it I get this error:
[image]

This is what is in the log file on the server:

```
KUP-05004:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because parallel select was not requested.

Field Definitions for table LD_CMS_BASIS_MIGRATION
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Rows with all null fields are accepted

  Fields in Data Source: 

    CONTRACT_NUMBER                 CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    PRODUCTCODE                     CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    TRANSACTION_NUMBER              CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    EFFECTIVE_DATE                  CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    AMENDMENT                       CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    TERM                            CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    ACTIVE                          CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    AGENT_NUMBER                    CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    PREMIUM                         CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    ICRATE                          CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    RCRATE                          CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    IC_ALLOW                        CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    RC_ALLOW                        CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    SPRATE                          CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    TRANSACTION_CODE                CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    TRANSACTION_DATE                CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    AGENT_CATEGORY                  CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    AGENT_SALES_CODE                CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    FREQ                            CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    TOT_PREMTD                      CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    REFERENCE                       CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    ALTERNATIVE_COMMISSION_METHOD   CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    PAXUS_REF_ID                    CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
KUP-04117: Field name PAXUS_REF_ID
 was not found in the access parameter field list or table.
KUP-04093: error processing the FIELD NAMES record in data file /u02/CAMS/MIGRATIONS/dataload/CMS_BASIS_MIG.csv
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mac

##################  EDIT

Answer from Tajesh below, pretty much. This is what worked. I think the Newline command is what mostly did the trick. When I had edited the CSV file and added a comma at the end of each line the it picked up the last column just fine. I did also have to add the date mask too. But, Tajesh solution means that I don't need to edit the CSV file.

```
create table LD_CMS_BASIS_MIGRATION
(
  contract_number               VARCHAR2(8),
  productcode                   VARCHAR2(3),
  transaction_number            NUMBER,
  effective_date                DATE,
  amendment                     VARCHAR2(3),
  term                          NUMBER,
  active                        VARCHAR2(1),
  agent_number                  VARCHAR2(5),
  premium                       NUMBER,
  icrate                        NUMBER,
  rcrate                        NUMBER,
  ic_allow                      NUMBER,
  rc_allow                      NUMBER,
  sprate                        NUMBER,
  transaction_code              VARCHAR2(4),
  transaction_date              DATE,
  agent_category                VARCHAR2(4),
  agent_sales_code              VARCHAR2(4),
  freq                          VARCHAR2(1),
  tot_premtd                    NUMBER,
  reference                     VARCHAR2(40),
  alternative_commission_method VARCHAR2(40),
  paxus_ref_id                  VARCHAR2(8)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY "MIGRATIONS" ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
            BADFILE 'CMS_BASIS_MIG_BAD.bad'
            LOGFILE 'CMS_BASIS_MIG_LOG.log'
            SKIP 1
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "dd/mm/yyyy"
            MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    ) LOCATION ( 'CMS_BASIS_MIG.csv' )
) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
    PARALLEL 5;
```

Comment: CSV file contains 17 values. External table lists 23 of them. What happens if you match those lists?

Comment: Hi there, sorry but I made a mess of the question. I had listed the wrong input file in the definition. I have it listed correctly now and with the correct error listed. Can I simply add the column headings like I'm trying to do? Previously I used external tables with fixed width columns and I had to define the column attributes also?

Comment: fwiw, Jeff Smith, the Oracle SQL Developer product manager and part time stackoverflow participant, has created a nice youtube video on this topic here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R8I27dgvy4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with the following create table syntax?

```
create table LD_CMS_BASIS_MIGRATION
(
  contract_number               VARCHAR2(8),
  productcode                   VARCHAR2(3),
  transaction_number            NUMBER,
  effective_date                DATE,
  amendment                     VARCHAR2(3),
  term                          NUMBER,
  active                        VARCHAR2(1),
  agent_number                  VARCHAR2(5),
  premium                       NUMBER,
  icrate                        NUMBER,
  rcrate                        NUMBER,
  ic_allow                      NUMBER,
  rc_allow                      NUMBER,
  sprate                        NUMBER,
  transaction_code              VARCHAR2(4),
  transaction_date              DATE,
  agent_category                VARCHAR2(4),
  agent_sales_code              VARCHAR2(4),
  freq                          VARCHAR2(1),
  tot_premtd                    NUMBER,
  reference                     VARCHAR2(40),
  alternative_commission_method VARCHAR2(40),
  paxus_ref_id                  VARCHAR2(8)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY "MIGRATIONS" ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
            BADFILE 'CMS_BASIS_MIG_BAD.bad'
            LOGFILE 'CMS_BASIS_MIG_LOG.log'
            SKIP 1
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    ) LOCATION ( 'CMS_BASIS_MIG.csv' )
) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
    PARALLEL 5;
```

If the mentioned code throws an error of any type of "date conversion", then you must have to specify each column name and their format if the column's data type is the date. Example: [conversion format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#i1009331)

Comment: Perfect, it also needed the DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "dd/mm/yyyy" and then I can read from it fine.

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests "KUP-04117: Field name PAXUS_REF_ID
 was not found in the access parameter field list or table.", Oracle was unable to find a value for the column PAXUS_REF_ID, instead, it's getting a new line character as there is no value populated for this column after the last comma of the record, because of which it's throwing an error.

I have modified the second and third rows of the CSV file as below and it's generating the output as expected.

Added value 0 to the second record and white space for the third at the end of the record. After the change, External table is able to read both of these records

```
CONTRACT_NUMBER,PRODUCTCODE,TRANSACTION_NUMBER,EFFECTIVE_DATE,AMENDMENT,TERM,ACTIVE,AGENT_NUMBER,PREMIUM,ICRATE,RCRATE,IC_ALLOW,RC_ALLOW,SPRATE,TRANSACTION_CODE,TRANSACTION_DATE,AGENT_CATEGORY,AGENT_SALES_CODE,FREQ,TOT_PREMTD,REFERENCE,ALTERNATIVE_COMMISSION_METHOD,PAXUS_REF_ID
PAXUSCT1,MAA,1,07/10/2017,NB,12,Y,2905,6000,,,1,1,,T642,,,,,6000,,,0
PAXUSCT1,MAA,2,07/05/2018,INC,11,Y,2905,2400,90,3,1,1,,,,,,,8400,,,
PAXUSCT2,MAA,1,01/06/2018,NB,12,Y,T1000,540,,,1,1,,,,,,,540,,,
PAXUSCT3,MAA,1,05/06/2018,NB,12,Y,T1000,1200,,,1,1,,,,,,,1200,,,
```

To fix this, as suggested by @Hotfix, you will have to include below mentioned statement in you access parameters

```
missing field values are null
```

Also, if you face any issue with interpreting date column data, you can add below date formatter, to your access parameters.

```
date_format date mask "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Apart from this, your dataset seems to have issues with the values of column agent_number as well for records 4 and 5, which has value T1000 for a number column.

Answer (score 1):

missing values in your csv file are the problem. you Need to convert them to null. just add `MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL` in `ACCESS PARAMETERS`

```
 access parameters 
  (
    records field names all files
    fields CSV without embedded record Terminators
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
  )
```