# How to enter user input on SQL to get output

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, plsql

I need to add multiple users to select input which will fetch the data on the database in one specific file.

example:

```
select * from <table Name> where <column_Name> (which will take from specific  file) in <value>(this also need to come from the file )
```

Is this operation we perform in Oracle 12c the file format will be like this

```
<table Name>  <value>
<table Name> <value>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please explain more your question.

I supose, you have a CSV file. you can import data from csv file. If you use EXTERNAL TABLES. you can use the csv file like a table and you can join the external tables with your tables

you can read about external tables in this link
[Import a CSV file into an Oracle External Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477426/import-a-csv-file-into-an-oracle-external-table)